# Symfony 3 Nelmio cors set allow origin properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, nelmiocorsbundle

I want to give limit access only allow some address to access my restful API, I using symfony and nelmio cors bundle.

this is my config from documetation :

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api':
            allow_origin: ['192.0.74.122']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: ['^api\.']
```

I want to set `192.0.74.122` only allowed to access the `^/api` and `^/api/*`, but when I test in browser, postman and jquery ajax call, it can be from localhost or `127.0.0.1`.

please help me how to block from other address beside the allowed addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Nelmio cors bundle is about setting CORS headers not about blocking or restricting access to specific routes.

Use `access_control` entries in your `security.yml` for that.
Example (not tested):

```
# config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 192.0.74.122 }
        - { path: ^/api, role: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

You can set multiple IPs or even ranges. See the [official cookbook page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#matching-access-control-by-ip) a for detailed explanation.